# Is there any fiscal responsibility merit to Congress's plan to use IRS funds to pay for Israeli relief?

Tags: united-states, congress, israel, budget

The U.S. Congress is debating a plan to take $14 Billion dollars allocated to the Internal Revenue Service (IRS) or tax collectors and give it to Israel for emergency aid.   The idea for this as stated is fiscal responsibility / pay as you go.

My question is: does this fiscal responsibility motivation have merit? Not looking for opinions, looking for analytical analysis on the bill, ideally from bipartisan organizations.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, there is no merit to this idea and it would actually cause the deficit to increase.

[MEMORANDUM: Cuts to IRS tax enforcement would increase the deficit](https://www.budget.senate.gov/chairman/newsroom/press/memorandum-cuts-to-irs-tax-enforcement-would-increase-the-deficit)

> - October 17, 2023 - CBO estimated that an appropriations amendment to    cut $25 billion from the IRS would:
>
>   - Reduce revenues by $49 billion over ten years
>   - Increase the deficit on net by $24 billion over ten years
> - June 1, 2023 - CBO estimated that cutting $21.4 billion from the IRS    as part of the Fiscal Responsibility Act would:
>
>   - Reduce revenues by $40.4 billion over ten years
>   - Increase the deficit on net by $19 billion over ten years
> - April 25, 2023 - CBO estimated that cutting $71.5 billion from the    IRS as part of the Default on America Act would:
>
>   - Reduce revenues by $191 billion over ten years
>   - Increase the deficit on net by $120 billion over ten years
> - January 9, 2023 - CBO estimated that cutting $71.5 billion from the    IRS as part of the first bill that the Republican-controlled House
>   voted on would:
>
>   - Reduce revenues by $186 billion over ten years
>   - Increase the deficit on net by $114 billion over ten years

Comment: How do we know the CBO's numbers are correct, though? They're using a linear model where each marginal dollar contributed to the IRS increases government revenues by $5 but this is a gross oversimplification.

Comment: @JonathanReez are you suggesting that cutting money to tax enforcement won’t cause a decrease in tax revenue?

Comment: @JoeW it depends on how effective the marginal dollar is for the IRS. If each additional dollar results in <$1 in additional revenue then it would be beneficial to cut the IRS budget. I don't trust the $5 figure.

Comment: @JonathanReez even if it is under a dollar we would still be losing money in the long run. That aside I don’t trust the idea that the numbers are that far off.

Comment: I seem to recall they also wanted to ban the IRS from reporting on how much its inability to collect taxes properly was impacting the deficit.

Answer (score 18):

Not according to accountants, no.  See [CBO](https://www.cbo.gov/publication/57444):

> How CBO Estimates the Effect on Revenues of Increased IRS Funding
> CBO’s estimate of revenues is based on the IRS’s projected returns on investment (ROIs) for spending on new enforcement initiatives. The IRS estimates those ROIs by calculating the expected revenues that would be raised from taxes, interest, and penalties as a result of the new initiatives and dividing them by their additional cost. (The agency has provided ROIs over the past five years as part of its budget justification.) The IRS’s ROIs ramp up over three years as staff become trained and fully productive, arrive at the peak level, and then stay there. In recent years, peak ROIs have ranged from 5 to 9. **That is, a $1 increase in spending on the IRS’s enforcement activities results in $5 to $9 of increased revenues.**

###### Decreased funding => decreased revenue => increased deficits.

But the math doesn't matter all that much, since there is sizable chunk of the Republican political class and base [that hate the IRS on sight](https://www.cnn.com/2023/01/23/politics/irs-fair-tax-republicans-abolish/index.html).

> Within the first week of the new Congress, a dozen GOP lawmakers introduced a bill that would abolish the IRS altogether and replace the entire federal tax code with a national sales tax.

Comment: Are there any independent corroborations to the idea that each marginal dollar contributed to the IRS increases revenue by "$5 to $9", given current IRS staffing and spending? I.e. if we spend $1 trillion on the IRS, surely we won't get $5 trillion in additional revenue? In other words, the effectiveness of each marginal dollar likely decreases exponentially at some point, but the CBO sort of assumes that such a point does not exist.

Comment: CBO **is** independent.  That's their job.  And, yes, you've made this claim to me before.  And, no, I did not find it credible then.

Comment: @JonathanReez https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative

Comment: @JonathanReez "The average error for CBO’s budget-year revenue projections is 1.2 percent" -- 2020 CBO report "An Evaluation of CBO's Past Revenue Projections" So it sounds like the numbers are pretty solid.

Comment: @codeMonkey the US budget is $6 trillion, 1.2 percent of that is $72 billion. Meanwhile they project that cutting the IRS budget by $25b would reduce revenue by $5 billion/year. Seems well within their margin of error. I'm sure they get the biggest projections correctly but I'd question them for small decisions like this.

Comment: @JonathanReez True, but it depends what that 1.2% refers to.  If it pertain's to the accepted answer's "*Increase the deficit on net by $24 billion over ten years*", then being 1.2% off is rather benign.  And if they are that close on aggregate numbers, then it seems rather wishful thinking to *know* they'll be off on smaller component parts to that aggregate.

Comment: @JonathanReez - That's not how statistics work. You don't assign 100% of the error to the tiny subset of the data that you don't like.  And you're completely missing the point that **they publish their results for the world to fact check.** If they were consistently wrong about IRS funding, serious math people would point out their wrongness. That's how peer review works.

Comment: @codeMonkey we're talking about a prediction of the total tax revenue and it's perfectly reasonable to apply a 1.2% error margin for *that* number.